# python asynchronization

Tags: python

Imagine a text file of 20 mb. I am reading char by char and extracting the useful information. I have actually 2 main functions, one is reading the file and the second is extracting the info. Something like this:

```
def reader(path):
    f = open(path, 'r')
    source = f.read()
    f.close()

    while True:
        # here is where I read char by char and call the function extractor

def extractor(s):
    # here I extract the useful information
```

Now, my goal is to continue to read while extractor is working. So basicaly, my question is what is the appropriate way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Which version of Python? Because in 3.2+, I recommend concurrent.futures module.

Comment: Are you actually seeing a performance problem without concurrent read and process? Reading 20MB from a modern hard disk should take only a couple of seconds, so gaining that time back is the absolute limit on the potential speedup.

Comment: Well actually, I am writing a program that will connect several websites, so I feel like speeding up even a nanosecond from anywhere I can would be in my favor.

Comment: If your program require connecting to multiple sources/websites and receivers, then you should consider Twisted for even-driven (asychronous) application: http://twistedmatrix.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use producer/consumer threads. The threads can be synchronized using a `Queue.Queue`.

**EDIT**: an example of a producer/consumer system:

```
from threading import Thread
from Queue import Queue


def produce(queue, n_items):
    for d in range(n_items):
        queue.put(d)
        print "put {0} in queue".format(d)

def consume(queue, n_items):
    d = 0
    while d != n_items -1: # You need some sort of stop condition
        d = queue.get()
        print "got {0} from queue".format(d)

def start_producer_and_consumer(wait):
    q = Queue()
    consumer_thread = Thread(target = consume, args = (q, 10))
    producer_thread = Thread(target = produce, args = (q, 10))
    producer_thread.start()
    consumer_thread.start()
    if wait:
        producer_thread.join()
        consumer_thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_producer_and_consumer(True)
```

As you will see if you execute this, everything will be consumed in the correct order.

Comment: I am having problems with threading. For instance, if I put 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in the queue using threading, I strangely receive a result like 1,3,4,5,2,6,8,7,9

Comment: Edited my answer to address that.